# How do I conditionally render <h2>{title}</>?

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, switch-statement

I have three React components: Card, ItemForm, ItemDetails. I've tried countless different ways of rendering and conditionally rendering the `<h2>{title}</h2>` in the Card. I want to change the text inside the h2 tag when the Card component is rendered in the ItemForm and then change again when the ItemForm component is rendered in the ItemDetails component.

```
// Card.jsx component

import React from "react";

const item = [
    <b className="location">Location:</b>,
    <b className="category">Category:</b>,
    <b className="item">Item:</b>,
    <b className="description">Description:</b>,
    <b className="uom">Unit of Measure:</b>,
    <b className="case">Case Size:</b>,
    <b className="vendor">Vendor Name:</b>,
    <b className="vc">Vender Code:</b>
];

const inventoryItem = item.map((content, index) => <li key={index}>{content}</li>);

const Card = ({ title, children }) => {

    return (
        <div className="card">
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <div>
                <ul className="cardUl">{inventoryItem}{children}</ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Card
```

```
// ItemForm.jsx

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import Card from "../components/Card"

const ItemForm = (props) => {

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
                <Card
                    id="homeCard"
                    title="Item Form"
                >
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        defaultValue={props.newItem.location}
                        onChange={props.handleChange}
                        name={'location'}
                        placeholder={'location'}
                        className='locationInput'
                    />
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        defaultValue={props.newItem.category}
                        onChange={props.handleChange}
                        name={'category'}
                        placeholder={'category'}
                        className='categoryInput'
                    />
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        defaultValue={props.newItem.item_name}
                        onChange={props.handleChange}
                        name={'item_name'}
                        placeholder={'item'}
                        className='itemInput'
                    />
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        defaultValue={props.newItem.description}
                        onChange={props.handleChange}
                        name={'description'}
                        placeholder={'description'}
                        className='descriptionInput'
                    />
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        defaultValue={props.newItem.unit_measure}
                        onChange={props.handleChange}
                        name={'unit_measure'}
                        placeholder={'unit of measure'}
                        className='uomInput'
                    />
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        defaultValue={props.newItem.case_size}
                        onChange={props.handleChange}
                        name={'case_size'}
                        placeholder={'case size'}
                        className='caseInput'
                    />
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        defaultValue={props.newItem.vendor_name}
                        onChange={props.handleChange}
                        name={'vendor_name'}
                        placeholder={'vendor_name'}
                        className='vendorInput'
                    />
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        defaultValue={props.newItem.vendor_code}
                        onChange={props.handleChange}
                        name={'vendor_code'}
                        placeholder={'vendor_code'}
                        className='vcInput'
                    />
                    <button
                        type="submit"
                        className="addButton"
                    >
                        Add Item
                    </button>
                </Card>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}

export default ItemForm
```

```
// ItemDetails.jsx

import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios'
import { BASE_URL } from '../globals'
import ItemForm from '../components/ItemForm';

const ItemDetails = (props) => {
    let navigate = useNavigate()
    let { id } = useParams()

    const getItem = async () => {
        let item = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/item/${id}`)
        props.setNewItem(item.data[0])
        // console.log(item.data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getItem();
    }, [])

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        props.setNewItem({ ...props.newItem, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    const handleDelete = async (_id) => {
        await axios.delete(`${BASE_URL}/item/delete/${id}`).then(
            () => navigate('items'))
    }

    const updateItem = async () => {
        let url = `${BASE_URL}/item/update/${id}`
        await axios.put({
            url,
            method: 'put',
            data: props.newItem
        })
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        updateItem();
        props.setNewItem({
            location: '',
            category: '',
            item_name: '',
            description: '',
            unit_measure: '',
            case_size: '',
            count: '',
            vendor_name: '',
            vendor_code: ''
        })
        axios.put(`${BASE_URL}/item/update/${id}`, props.newItem)
        navigate('/items');
    }

    return (
        <div className='items'>
            <h1>Edit</h1>
            <ItemForm
                title="Edit Item"
                newItem={props.newItem}
            />
            <button
                onClick={() => handleSubmit}
            >
                Save
            </button>
            <div onClick={() => handleDelete(props.newItem._id)}>
                <button id='deleteButton' type='submit'>Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default ItemDetails
```

I tried passing the {title} through props but title stayed the same when ItemForm was rendered into ItemDetails. I wanted to try and implement the switch statement below inside the Card component but I'm stuck on how

```
let banana = document.getElementById("cardHeader").innerHTML.trim();
    switch (banana) {

        case "CreateNewItem":
            console.log(document.getElementById("cardHeader").innerHTML);
            document.getElementById.innerHTML = "Create A New Item";
            console.log(document.getElementById("cardHeader").innerHTML + "(HAS CHANGED)")
            break;
        case "EditItem":
            console.log(document.getElementById("cardHeader").innerHTML);
            document.getElementById("cardHeader").innerHTML = `Edit ${props.newItem.item_name}`;
            console.log(document.getElementById("cardHeader").innerHTML + "(HAS CHANGED")
            break;
        default:
            console.log(document.getElementById("cardHeader").innerHTML);
            document.getElementById.innerHTML = `Default Case`;
            console.log(document.getElementById("cardHeader").innerHTML + "(HAS CHANGED")

    }
```

I've tried useState and useEffect

```
// Card.jsx

const Card = ({ title, children }) => {

    console.log("Card.jsx:", title)
    const [cardTitle, setCardTitle] = useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        async function updateTitle() {
            if (title) {
                await setCardTitle(title);
            }
        }
        updateTitle();
    }, [title]);

    return (
        <div className="card">
            <h2>{cardTitle}</h2>
            <div>
                <ul className="cardUl">{inventoryItem}{children}</ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Card
```

```
// ItemForm.jsx

const ItemForm = (props) => {

    console.log("ItemForm.jsx:", props)

    const [cardTitle, setCardTitle] = useState("Item Form")

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
                <Card
                    className="homeCard"
                    title={cardTitle}
                >
```

```
// ItemDetails.jsx

const ItemDetails = (props, { title }) => {
    console.log("ItemDetails.jsx:", props)

    const [cardTitle, setCardTitle] = useState("Edit Item")

useEffect(() => {
        async function updateTitle() {
            if (title) {
                await setCardTitle(title);
            }
        }
        updateTitle();
    }, [title]);

return (
        <div className='items'>
            <h1>Edit</h1>
            <ItemForm
                title={cardTitle}
                newItem={props.newItem}
            />
```

Comment: You are passing a fixed `title` prop using `<Card ... title="Item Form">`, yet you say you tried changing it in many ways. Explain in what ways you tried to change it, because it does not become clear from the code (which only contains the single fixed `title` value). You should never try to "fix" or "override" your React code by using `document.getElementById()`, you should work *with* React and not *against* it (because if you do, then sooner or later it will work against you).

Comment: You need to pass the title prop in ItemForm as a variable which is also passing the same prop from ItemDetails, if you can give a default value on ItemForm it is going to help. If you do not pass any title prop from ItemDetails to ItemForm the default value will be passed to Card element. But if you pass a title prop value from ItemDetails to ItemForm, the given prop value will be used to render the title in Card element.

Comment: @PeterB I've been trying to also implement useState and useEffect to change the state of ```title``` value